# $8^a=3$ and $3^b=5$ and $10^c=5$ then find $c$ in terms of $a$ and $b$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

if $8^a=3$ and $3^b=5$ and $10^c=5$ then find $c$ using $a$ and $b$.

**My Attempt:**

if $8^a=3$ and $3^b=5$ then we can say that $8^{ab}=5$ and then we have $2^{3ab}=10^c$ but i cant solve this equation.

Comment: Note:  "calculus" is not a good tag (there is no calculus here).  "algebra-precalculus" and/or "exponentiation" are more appropriate.

Comment: No problem.  Good question to wake up on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have $$2^{3a}=3\implies 2^{3ab}=5\implies 2\times 2^{3ab}=10\implies 2^{3ab+1}=10$$

Thus $$10^c=2^{c(3ab+1)}$$  But we know that $2^{3ab}=5$ so we are asked to solve $$c(3ab+1)=3ab\implies c=\frac {3ab}{3ab+1}$$

Comment: thats amazing thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

$$8^a=3\implies3a\log2=\log3$$

Similarly, $$b\log3=\log5$$ and $$\log5=c(\log5+\log2)\iff(c-1)\log5=c\log2$$

$$\implies3a\log2\cdot b\log3\cdot(c-1)\log5=\log3\cdot \log5\cdot c\log2$$

$$\iff3a\cdot b(c-1)=c$$

**See**: [Laws of Logarithms](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Laws_of_Logarithms)